# How to validate for checkbox selection if all checkbox have same name?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Hi All
I have a group of check box having same name so as to get the array of single variable when it is posted on serverside for exampleL

```
<input type="checkbox" name="midlevelusers[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="midlevelusers[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="midlevelusers[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="midlevelusers[]" value="1">
```

I need a javascript validation to check whether any checkbox is selected or not?

Thanks and Regards

NOTE: I need javascript validation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<form name="myform" method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return checkTheBox();">
  <input type="checkbox" name="midlevelusers[]" value="1" /> 1 &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="midlevelusers[]" value="2" /> 2 &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="midlevelusers[]" value="3" /> 3 &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="midlevelusers[]" value="4" /> 4 &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="checkbox" name="midlevelusers[]" value="5" /> 5 &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkTheBox() {
    var flag = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i< 5; i++) {
      if(document.myform["midlevelusers[]"][i].checked){
        flag ++;
      }
    }
    if (flag != 1) {
      alert ("You must check one and only one checkbox!");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can access the DOM elements and check their `checked` property. For instance:

```
var list, index, item, checkedCount;

checkedCount = 0;
list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    item = list[index];
    if (item.getAttribute('type') === "checkbox"
        && item.checked
        && item.name === "midlevelusers[]") {
        ++checkedCount;
    }
 }
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/okuwi5)

There we're looking through the *whole document*, which may not be efficient. If you have a container around these (and presumably you do, a `form` element), then you can give that element an ID and then look only within it (only the `var`, `form =`, and `list =` lines are new/different):

```
var form, list, index, item, checkedCount;

checkedCount = 0;
form = document.getElementById('theForm');
list = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
    item = list[index];
    if (item.getAttribute('type') === "checkbox"
        && item.checked
        && item.name === "midlevelusers[]") {
        ++checkedCount;
    }
 }
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/okuwi5/3)

---

**Off-topic**: You haven't mentioned using a library, so I haven't used one above, but FWIW this stuff is *much* easier if you use one like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). For instance, with jQuery:

```
var checkedCount = $("input[type=checkbox][name^=midlevelusers]:checked").length;
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/okuwi5/2) Other libraries will be similar, though the details will vary.

Comment: Thanks for posting the jQuery method - much easier than what I was doing before.

Answer (score 4):

try,

```
function validate() {
    var chk = document.getElementsByName('midlevelusers[]')
    var len = chk.length

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
         if(chk[i].checked){
        return true;
          }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

use id's

```
<input type="checkbox" name="midlevelusers[]" id="mlu1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="midlevelusers[]" id="mlu2" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="midlevelusers[]" id="mlu3" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="midlevelusers[]" id="mlu4" value="4">
```

now you can do

```
for (var i=1;i<5;i++){
  var el = document.getElementById('mlu'+i);
  if (el.checked) { /* do something */}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function would alert whether or not a checkbox has any values checked.

```
function isChecked(checkboxarray){
    for (counter = 0; counter < checkboxarray.length; counter++){
        if (checkboxarray[counter].checked){
            alert("Checkbox has at least one checked");
        else{
            alert("None checked");
        }
```

You would need to add a bit more to do what you actually want to do with it but that will get you on the right track I think!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `jQuery` and do it this way:

```
if($('input[name="light[]"]:checked').length < 1){
            alert("Please enter the light conditions");
}
```